# How to properly implement a onClickItem from a search activity's listview

Tags: android, listview, search, android-contentprovider

I have a search activity (ActivitySearch.java) the correctly returns results when I use the soft keyboards 'Go' button, it returns all result from the search suggestions.  I using a Content Provider and Cursor LoaderCallbacks.  This is my first time trying to LoaderCallbacks and doing a search activity.

Now I want to be able to click on one of the suggested results via the onClickItem/onClickItemListenter,  and have it return to the search listview for final choice by the user, but I know my code isn't right, obviously.  FYI, I've enabled all my activities in the project as searchable.  I've looked at a bunch of samples but I haven't been able to glean the correct method.

I'm using a simple activity (ActivityFloor.java) that I'm hitting the hardware search key on, just a few buttons, that kick off intents.

My search activity uses the default android view for the listview results. It also inherits it's activity from MyListActivity, but this is for supporting a common menu.

Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.birdsall.tda"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
     android:exported="true" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID" android:value="id=12345" />

    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_OPEN" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.12345" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/png" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/jpg" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".ActivitySearch" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.birdsall.tda.ActivityMain"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ActivityFloor" >
    </activity>


    <provider
        android:name="com.birdsall.tda.TDAProvider"
        android:authorities="com.birdsall.tda.contentprovidertda"
        android:exported="true"
        android:readPermission="true"
        android:writePermission="true" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ActivitySearch"
        android:label="Rule Search"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Here's my searchable.xml in res/xml

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:searchSettingsDescription="@string/search_description"
android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.birdsall.tda.contentprovidertda"
android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
android:searchSuggestIntentData="content://com.birdsall.tda.TDAProvider/rules"
android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer" >

</searchable>
```

Here's my search activity (ActivitySearch.java):

```
package com.birdsall.tda;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class ActivitySearch extends MyListActivity implements 
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {


private static String QUERY_EXTRA_KEY = "QUERY_EXTRA_KEY";

private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
private final String TAG = "ActivitySearch";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");

    View mListView  = getListView();

    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate ... after setOnItemClickListener");

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onCreate ... after setOnItemClickListener", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // Create a new adapter and bind it to the List View
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
            new String[] { TDAdb.COL_RULETITLE },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }, 0);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // Initiate the Cursor Loader
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    // Get the launch Intent
    parseIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Log.i(TAG, "onNewIntent");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onNewIntent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    parseIntent(getIntent());

}



private void parseIntent(Intent intent) {
    // If the Activity was started to service a Search request,
    // extract the search query.
    Log.i(TAG, "parseIntent");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "parseIntent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String searchQuery = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

        // Perform the search, passing in the search query as an argument
        // to the Cursor Loader
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(QUERY_EXTRA_KEY, searchQuery);

        // Restart the Cursor Loader to execute the new query.
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, args, this);
    }
}

public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateLoader");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onCreateLoader", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String query = "0";

    if (args != null) {
        // Extract the search query from the arguments.
        query = args.getString(QUERY_EXTRA_KEY);
    }

    // Construct the new query in the form of a Cursor Loader.
    String[] projection = { TDAdb.KEY_ROWID, TDAdb.COL_RULETITLE };
    String where = TDAdb.COL_RULETITLE + " LIKE \"%" + query + "%\"";
    String[] whereArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = TDAdb.COL_RULETITLE;

    // Create the new Cursor loader.
    return new CursorLoader(this, TDAProvider.CONTENT_URI_RULES,
            projection, where, whereArgs, sortOrder);
}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    // Replace the result Cursor displayed by the Cursor Adapter with
    // the new result set.
    Log.i(TAG, "onLoadFinished");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onLoadFinished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (adapter == null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onLoadFinished ... adapter is NULL");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onLoadFinished ... adapter is NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        this.finish();
    } 
    Log.i(TAG, "onLoadFinished ... adapter is valued");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onLoadFinished ... adapter is valued", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    adapter.swapCursor(cursor);     

}

public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    // Remove the existing result Cursor from the List Adapter.
    Log.i(TAG, "onLoaderReset");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onLoaderReset", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "handleIntent");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "handleIntent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // Gets the search query from the voice recognizer intent
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

        // Set the search box text to the received query and submit the
        // search
        // mSearchView.setQuery(query, true);
    }
}

  @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
    " search listview position:" + position,
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // Create a URI to the selected item.
    Uri selectedUri = 
      ContentUris.withAppendedId(TDAProvider.CONTENT_URI, id);

    // Create an Intent to view the selected item.
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(selectedUri);

    // Start an Activity to view the selected item.
    startActivity(intent);
  }

}
```

I NO LONGER GET ERRORS, THANKS TO [Micheal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1976626/michael-shrestha) (below), So the LOGCAT errors can be ignored.

I get errors, but only after trying to implement the onClickItem coding from my logcat which I've included for completeness.

```
06-2923:56:57.416: I/TDAProvider(13786): query 
06-2923:56:57.439: W/SuggestionsAdapter(13786): Search suggestions query threw an exception.
06-2923:56:57.439: W/SuggestionsAdapter(13786): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
06-2923:56:57.439: W/SuggestionsAdapter(13786):     at android.net.Uri$PathSegments.get(Uri.java:978)
06-2923:56:57.439: W/SuggestionsAdapter(13786):     at android.net.Uri$PathSegments.get(Uri.java:963)
06-2923:56:57.439: W/SuggestionsAdapter(13786):     at com.birdsall.tda.TDAProvider.query(TDAProvider.java:180)
06-2923:56:57.439: W/SuggestionsAdapter(13786):     at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:652)
06-2923:56:57.439: W/SuggestionsAdapter(13786):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:189)
06-2923:56:57.439: W/SuggestionsAdapter(13786):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:370)
06-2923:56:57.439: W/SuggestionsAdapter(13786):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:313)
06-2923:56:57.439: W/SuggestionsAdapter(13786):     at android.app.SearchManager.getSuggestions(SearchManager.java:823)
06-2923:56:57.439: W/SuggestionsAdapter(13786):     at android.widget.SuggestionsAdapter.runQueryOnBackgroundThread(SuggestionsAdapter.java:190)
06-2923:56:57.439: W/SuggestionsAdapter(13786):     at android.widget.CursorFilter.performFiltering(CursorFilter.java:49)
06-2923:56:57.439: W/SuggestionsAdapter(13786):     at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
06-2923:56:57.439: W/SuggestionsAdapter(13786):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-2923:56:57.439: W/SuggestionsAdapter(13786):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-2923:56:57.439: W/SuggestionsAdapter(13786):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
06-2923:57:00.002: I/TDAProvider(13786): query 
06-2923:57:00.049: I/TDAProvider(13786): query return cursor 
06-2923:57:00.635: I/TDAProvider(13786): query 
06-2923:57:00.635: I/TDAProvider(13786): query return cursor 
06-2923:57:01.275: I/TDAProvider(13786): query 
06-2923:57:01.275: I/TDAProvider(13786): query return cursor 
06-2923:57:02.650: W/InputEventReceiver(13786): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
06-2923:57:02.689: I/ActivitySearch(13786): onCreate
06-2923:57:02.728: D/AndroidRuntime(13786): Shutting down VM
06-2923:57:02.728: W/dalvikvm(13786): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e1b2a0)
06-2923:57:02.728: E/AndroidRuntime(13786): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-2923:57:02.728: E/AndroidRuntime(13786): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.birdsall.tda/com.birdsall.tda.ActivitySearch}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.birdsall.tda.ActivitySearch cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
06-2923:57:02.728: E/AndroidRuntime(13786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2136)
06-2923:57:02.728: E/AndroidRuntime(13786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2174)
06-2923:57:02.728: E/AndroidRuntime(13786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-2923:57:02.728: E/AndroidRuntime(13786):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1267)
06-2923:57:02.728: E/AndroidRuntime(13786):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-2923:57:02.728: E/AndroidRuntime(13786):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-2923:57:02.728: E/AndroidRuntime(13786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
06-2923:57:02.728: E/AndroidRuntime(13786):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-2923:57:02.728: E/AndroidRuntime(13786):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-2923:57:02.728: E/AndroidRuntime(13786):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
06-2923:57:02.728: E/AndroidRuntime(13786):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
06-2923:57:02.728: E/AndroidRuntime(13786):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-2923:57:02.728: E/AndroidRuntime(13786): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.birdsall.tda.ActivitySearch cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
06-2923:57:02.728: E/AndroidRuntime(13786):     at com.birdsall.tda.ActivitySearch.onCreate(ActivitySearch.java:39)
06-2923:57:02.728: E/AndroidRuntime(13786):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5058)
06-2923:57:02.728: E/AndroidRuntime(13786):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-2923:57:02.728: E/AndroidRuntime(13786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
06-2923:57:02.728: E/AndroidRuntime(13786):     ... 11 more
06-2923:57:04.392: I/Process(13786): Sending signal. PID: 13786 SIG: 9
```

Thanks for the time and help, in advance.

Here's the gist of MyActivity, just a common menu for my Activities.

```
package com.birdsall.tda;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {

String selectParam = "";

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityMain.class);
          intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
          startActivity(intent);
          return true;

    case R.id.am_index:
        Intent i1 = new Intent(this, ActivityIndex.class);
        startActivity(i1);
        return true;    

        /*  ...    More menu items */

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: what is `MyListActivity`?

Comment: I mentioned it above, it is an override of Activity, it just has common menu info, I added the source.

Comment: I took a working Search Activity from another project and replaced my code with it and I still get the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spent about 2 weeks on this on and off and my code has changed a bit.  I found the setContentView and my local layout were the issue for not getting results.  I'll post a new version on the code.  Thanks all.

```
package com.birdsall.tda;

import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.app.SearchableInfo;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ActivitySearch extends MyListActivity implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private static String QUERY_EXTRA_KEY = "QUERY_EXTRA_KEY";
private static final String TAG = "ActivitySearch";

private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
            new String[] { TDAdb.COL_RULETITLE },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }, 0);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    parseIntent(getIntent());


    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchableInfo searchableInfo = searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());

    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate at end");

}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Log.i(TAG, "onNewIntent");
    parseIntent(getIntent());
}

private void parseIntent(Intent intent) {

    Log.i(TAG, "parseIntent");

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String searchQuery = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        // Perform the search
        performSearch(searchQuery);
    }
}

private void performSearch(String query) {
    Log.i(TAG, "performSearch");
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(QUERY_EXTRA_KEY, query);

    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, args, this);
}

public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String query = "0";
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateLoader");
    if (args != null)
        query = args.getString(QUERY_EXTRA_KEY);

    String[] projection = { TDAdb.KEY_ROWID, TDAdb.COL_RULETITLE };
    String where = TDAdb.COL_RULETITLE + " LIKE \"%" + query + "%\"";

    String[] whereArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = TDAdb.COL_RULETITLE;

    return new CursorLoader(this, TDAProvider.CONTENT_URI_RULES,
            projection, where, whereArgs, sortOrder);
}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {

    adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Log.i(TAG, "onLoadFinished ... cursor has " + cursor.getCount()
            + " row(s)");
                + " row(s)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onLoaderReset");
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}

/**
 * Listing 8-28: Providing actions for search result selection
 */
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

    Log.i(TAG, "onListItemClick");

    Uri selectedUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
            TDAProvider.CONTENT_URI_RULES, id);

    Intent i = new Intent(ActivitySearch.this, ActivityRulesCrossRef.class);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("XRef", "N");
    String str_rowid = String.valueOf(id);
    extras.putString("selectedID", str_rowid);
    extras.putString("selectedRule", "Search");
    i.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();

}

public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface arg0) {
    finish();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick( ListView parent, View v, int position, long id)
{ 
//...
}
```

in your `Activity`

you dont need to set `listener` for that

hope this helps..

Comment: Eclipse complains about that: 'The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (ActivitySearch)
', so I changed it to the following: 'mListView.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);' but it still bombs out.  I'm thinking either I have the mListView misdefined or there's a search class that I have to override.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I got your suggestion to stop the program from bombing out, but I still get nothing in my listview after selecting an item.  I update the original ActivitySearch.